# Load facebox on body load

Tags: jquery-plugins, facebox

iam using facebox 1.1 and i want the facebox to load when the body loads, instead of clicking on the anchor tag with rel=facebox.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the [documentation](http://defunkt.github.com/facebox/)? It is described there under *Controlling Facebox Programmatically*.  Ok, it is facebox 1.2, I don't know if this is available in 1.1 but I think so.

E.g.:

```
$(function(){
    $.facebox({ div: '#box' });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i tried it already, it doesn't work.

Attach It onLoad

While calling facebox() on any anchor tag will do the trick, it's easier to give your Faceboxy links a rel="facebox" and hit them all onLoad.
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()
})

Perhaps it works only with 1.2 version.

Comment: @dskanth: Maybe. Sorry. Works for me.

Comment: I could make it work using body onload event and calling a function that fires a click event on the link.